# Not sure how to use addEventListener to watch for media query

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to run a function when the window is resized and hits a certain size. The following was working perfectly:

```
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)")
mobileSlider(mediaQuery) // Call listener function at run time
mediaQuery.addListener(mobileSlider) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

However, I got a warning that `addListener` is deprecated, so I'm attempting to change it without much success. I have tried the below, but doesn't work. What should I be doing?

```
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)")
mobileSlider(mediaQuery) // Call listener function at run time
window.addEventListener('resize', mobileSlider) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

I have also tried `window.addEventListener('resize', mobileSlider(mediaQuery))` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding an event listener on the `change` event from MediaQueryList.

I think this might help with your issue, please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#examples

Comment: When I initially changed `mediaQuery.addListener` to `mediaQuery.addEventListener`, it was causing an error that it required two paramenters. I should have realised it would just be `mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', mobileSlider)` which works perfectly. Thanks.